# Android LinearLayout How to position three buttons left, right and center?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Left,Center and Right Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623743/android-left-center-and-right-alignment)

I have three buttons which I would like to position at the horizontal  Left, Center, and Right within a linear layout and at the button of a parent vertical linear layout.  How can this be done?  I am not seeing any effect to applying android:gravity_center, right left.

Comment: You can start by showing what you have done instead of asking somebody to write the code for you.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you don't want a specific distance between the buttons (which can be hard to do with the different Android screen sizes) then you want to make sure you fill the parent and add them with center gravity. The [demo here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) can help you out a bit. Here is a code example.

Here is the resulting layout:

[image]

**Edit**: Based on your clarifying information, it is better to use a RelativeLayout to do what you want to accomplish. This is demonstrated in a number of questions on Stackoverflow. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623743/android-left-center-and-right-alignment/5623810#5623810). Here is the code from the answer.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="button1" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:id="@+id/button1button"></Button>
    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/firstedittext"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1button"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstedittext"
        android:text="button2" 
        android:id="@+id/button2button"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No This Does NOT even begin to answer the question.  I want one button to the LEFT one to the RIGHT and one in the center.

Comment: Sooooooooo                  like                                this

Comment: BUTTON------------------BUTTON------------------BUTTON

Comment: -------------------BUTTON--BUTTON--BUTTON----------------------

Comment: @barcodereader - You did not specify that in your original question. Please respond politely in the future to clarify (or update your question). I will update the answer.

Comment: Someone just close this out as a duplicate please.  It was answered correctly here:  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623743/android-left-center-and-right-alignment

Comment: @barcodereader: Try editing your question to show the BUTTON...BUTTON...BUTTON layout your require and also provide the layout xml file that you have tried using 'gravity' etc. If you do this then somebody may be able to show you why it isn't working the way you expect.