# Align two-button layout left and right in Android

Tags: android

I want to align two buttons with a linear layout, one on the left, and one on the right, like the next and previous buttons on an image gallery. I tried to align them but it doesn't work.

XML layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="bottom" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="prev"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Actual output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout`. There you can set `android:layout_alignParentLeft` and `android:layout_alignParentRight`.
This should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="bottom" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="prev"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if i want to put a TextView in between these buttons. This TextView should be vertically centered with respect to these buttons and should occupy full remaining space in center of these two buttons. Please help me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I solved it by using Linear Layout with layout_weight property.

Comment: @RobinPurbia yes you can use the code given below : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719521/2260963

Answer (score 9):

With Linear Layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Prev"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

With Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Prev"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Relative layout in your `LinearLayout`;

Also add  `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` to "prev" `Button`

and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to "next" `Button`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"    <---- ADD this prop
            android:text="prev" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"    <----- ADD this prop
            android:text="next" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your inner LinearLayout is of no-use. you can also remove it. Just add color property to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 5):

I guess, the simplest solution is to use View in your inner LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="prev"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Simple and neat... perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The idea is, to create a RelativeLayout as container and put first Button and then stick it to the right of parent view. After that, add Another button **inside** LinearLayout and set this LinearLayout into the left of first Button.

Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: you are right. I was just throwing layout while testing my code.

Comment: This is a nice trick because it will solve the text overlap issue. But doesn't feel standardized enough

Answer (score 3):

ur layout xml should be as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#fff">


 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
    <Button      
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:text="Pre" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Next" />
</RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` you can add the tags `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` on each button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RelativeLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="prev" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="next" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

(I used grey instead of white for the screenshot)
[image: LAYOUT]

Answer (score 1):

Use a FrameLayout and add the layout_gravity attribute in each of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this it will surely help you out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="@string/Linear"

                      android:textSize="35dp"
                      android:layout_margin="90dp"

            />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black">

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Relative"
                        />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
                        android:text="Constraint" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Use margin_Start and End to seprate the buttons in the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="-:Linear Layout:-"
              android:textSize="35sp"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
              tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Relative"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,HardcodedText"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
                android:text="Constraint"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    [enter image description here][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMYj2.png
```

Answer (score -1):

> For Better Performance:

Best to put two views left and right and one view between in linear layout rather than relative layout. Use the below code it will also remove the nesting of views .... It will be good in performance perpective :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="prev" />

        <TextView android:text="Hi its working"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Good, so add that in your answer.

Comment: While answering if you add a comparison context, you should mention a proper reasoning for that.

Comment: i have added it... any other way to add reason