# How to align a view to the left of another that is fixed in the center

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, user-interface, alignment

I want to create a layout like this:

```
|--------<Button>-<TextView>-<Button>--------|
```

The TextView in center, a Button at left and another at right.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: How? Becomes all one above the other when I use RelativeLayout.

Comment: Show what you have tried so we can help you adjust it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This should work according to what the OP wants. However, `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property and `View`s in a `RelativeLayout` are aligned to the top by default so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Now the textView is above the left button, that share the center with the right button. =/

Comment: @Neviat Didn't get you??

Comment: For high performance check the below link and make the width of the text view wrap content to achieve the above requirement  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719521/2260963

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```