# Android TextView Left Align and Right Align Text on the Same Line

Tags: android, android-layout, text-alignment

I need create `TextView` Left Align and Right Align Text on the Same Line, and output like this . I'm searching solution by using HTML text or something property Left Text and Right Text, some thing like method `setCompoundDrawables`

[image]

This is current **output**

[image]

and this is current code

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
int inPixels= (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.iconsize);
appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, inPixels, inPixels);
holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);

String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
Date date=new Date(packageInfo.firstInstallTime);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateText = df2.format(date);
holder.apkName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+appName+"</b>("+dateText+")"));
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Android TextView Left Align and Right Align Text on the Same Line

Comment: Oh so you want the text to be on  the Left corner as well as on the right corner?

Comment: yes , you are rigth

Comment: I don,t wan't use viewgroup , I know it's easily possible with viewgroup , with two TextView

Comment: I,m searching solution by using HTML text or something property Left Text and RIgth Text  some thing like method setcompounddrawable

Comment: Please mention that on the question too

Comment: You could put two Textviews in a RelativeLayout. See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222916/how-to-align-a-two-buttons-layout-left-and-right-in-android

Comment: @Kamil Ibadov post your xml :)

Comment: Let' me explain more, I have listview which every row consists one  textview , I set this textview left drawable , and need set rigth text

Comment: Also , I know use TableLayout, Custom rows which can use every viewgroup, but I don't want change code structure more, and need solution for a little time

Comment: @Kamil Ibadov you dont get the answer that you are looking as long as you dont post your xml we dont know that is the root how it works

Comment: In xml i have only ListView, I,m programmatically populate adapter and set to listview

Comment: Why not just use two textViews, your problem is already fixed mate

Comment: @Karun Shrestha so you want to display that name and version in two views?

Comment: Yes, two textviews

Comment: Use Tahmid's answer below, that might work with a single view

Comment: Yes , it look it must work , I,m just checking it . And I will say result

Comment: @Kamil Ibadov xoxo i saw your currant output as the expected one :P

Comment: @Charuක  what you mean in general? :)

Comment: @Kamil Ibadov i gave an answer and it was based on the wrong image heh now changed that!

Comment: I don't changed Image , I added image for more explanation

Comment: @Kamil Ibadov you have two images i gave the answer by looking at the second one that colorful one and chaged it

Comment: Not ! , I really not changed an image

Comment: @Charuක Thank you for question improvoment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid creating separate `TextView`, then you might need to use `SpannableString`.

I think, the solution is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521010/6155248)

You might get more idea through [this link](http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-spannablestring-part-2.html)

Comment: final String resultText = LeftText + "  " + RightText;
final SpannableString styledResultText = new SpannableString(resultText);
styledResultText.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), LeftText.length() + 2, LeftText.length() + 2 +RightText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
resultTextView.setText(styledResultText);

Comment: In the post exists some bugs ,etc  but idea SpannableString helped me. Thank!

Comment: Glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Using two textViews will give you the results:
Here's an example:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Text on the Left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Text on the Right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Hey Krunal there is mistake in your code.
if you are using weightSum then no need set layuot_width for child simply make it 0dp or don't set weightSum

Comment: @UmeshSonawane I've tried and this works.

There are a lot of ways to get a desired output.

Comment: I am not saying it doesn't work i just want to tell you if you are set layout_width then there is no use of weighSum

Comment: Yes, its ok if weightSum is removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how look after using SpannableString. And this is what I want. Thank you!

[image]

And final code is :

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
int inPixels= (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.iconsize);
appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, inPixels, inPixels);
holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);

String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
Date date=new Date(packageInfo.firstInstallTime);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateText = df2.format(date);
String LeftText=appName;
String RightText=dateText;
final String resultText = LeftText + "\n" + RightText;
final SpannableString styledResultText = new SpannableString(resultText);
styledResultText.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), LeftText.length() , LeftText.length() +RightText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.apkName.setText(styledResultText);
```

Comment: why this solution doesnt't work if there is no "\n" what if I want text in same line?